# Android, sending custom SEND intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to send intent for sharing link from my application, the standard way to send it is like this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

my problem that i want to have option to share with my application, so if i choice from my application to share some thing, i will see all the applications that have the ability of sharing content and i want to see my app there to, i can use the definition in manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

the question is, is there a way to send some extra data on the bundle spatial for my application share?
something like this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.putExtra(MY_EXTRA, extra_data_object);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Thanks for the help.